# Heroku doesn't update code

Tags: git, heroku, mean-stack

I have a MEAN app deployed on Heroku with automatic deploys from github enabled.
If I change something on .html files heroku deploys and changes are made but when I change .js, it deploys and the code changes on git, but if I check the changes using G.Chrome developer console, the code is still the same (it deploys after doing git commit and push)

Does anyone have an idea about what can be producing this?

Thanks for all

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Yep, I did. I decide to ask Heroku's support and it was node cache. I did sth similar to "heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false" on cmd. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Cool, glad you got it figured out. Feel free to post that info as an [answer to your own question](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because of node cache. The solution is as simple as writing on cmd (or linux terminal)

```
heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
```

This will add a variable to your project so that node cache will not cause more troubles.

After doing that you have to redeploy you app and that's all.